# Dragging google maps 3 with custom overlays causes VERY HUGE LAG

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, overlay-view, custom-overlay

I started using version 3, but there is a BIG problem.

When I create more than 20-30 custom overlays on the map AND try to drag the map with the mouse there is VERY HUGE lag.

When I use the build in control to pan the map there is NO lag.

Any idea what is happening? When I use version 2 the lag appears after adding more than 200 custom overlays. Version 3 start lagging with 20-30 only.

P.S. By custom overlay I mean subclassing OverlayView.

Here is example of the problem which appears mainly when using firefox

google maps v2: 46.233.14.168:8080/GoogleMapsTest/testPage2.jsp 
google maps v3: 46.233.14.168:8080/GoogleMapsTest/testPage.jsp

Comment: An example that exhibits the problem would be useful.

Comment: Ok, here are the examples. I uploaded them on a server where you can view the result using google maps v2 and google maps v3.

google maps v2: http://46.233.14.168:8080/GoogleMapsTest/testPage2.jsp
google maps v3: http://46.233.14.168:8080/GoogleMapsTest/testPage.jsp

When using google maps v2 while you drag the map everything is smooth but when using version 3 there is a HUGE LAG ( which is not appearing if you use the controls on the left to pan the map.)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the problem appears mainly when using Firefox. Other browsers handle it a little better but still not smooth as the previous version of google maps.

Comment: I have also experienced similar kind of lagging issues when using version 3 compared to version 2 of google map api and im bit of worried should I switch back to that version - also my few working colleagues reported lagging issues of firefox v. 14. so I am not yet completely sure is this google map api issue or firefox in general.

Comment: I don't see the problem (a VERY HUGE LAG, or even just a HUGE LAG) in any browser I use including FF 14.0.1.  Though you do have some labels that are above 85 degrees and off the map tiles.

Comment: Same for me. FF 13.0.1 on a Mac and it is fine.

Comment: Long time since you posted this - have you come accross a solution? I'm seeing similar behavior when playing around with google maps v3 and big overlays (files above 2Mb)

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem, with GM API 3 and an up-to-date Firefox. There where no performance problems with good old Firefox 11.

After some research, I found that the markers in my software were too complex - they consisted of a self-constructed div object with an image object inside.

I replaced them by standard `Google.maps.Marker`, which are less flexible but sufficient for my purpose. Now the map panning is blazingly fast - no problem with some thousand markers in Firefox, and even some ten thousands in Chrome!

Comment: The problem is with custom overlays compared to version maps api v2